# This loop wouldn't work correctly on the server?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming

I've added this code to the front-page.php in Wordpress theme and i added the featured images for the related posts but the result is this wrong message:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Resto 2\front-page.php on line 89
There has been a critical error on your website.
This is the loop that i want to use

```
<section id="features">
        <ul>
            <?php /*start the loop*/ ?>
            <?php $myquery = new WP_Query('category_name=menu-items&posts_per_page=4'); ?>
           <!--<?php while ( $myquery->have_posts() ) :  $myquery->the_post(); ?>-->
            <li>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?> "><?php the_title(); ?><a/>
                <span><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true); ?></span>
                <span class="star-<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rating', true); ?>rating"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </section>
```

Comment: There is no `endwhile` in your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `endwhile;` to your code.

```
<!--<?php while ( $myquery->have_posts() ) :  $myquery->the_post(); endwhile; ?>-->
```

or do different type of while:

```
<!--<?php while ( $myquery->have_posts() ){  $myquery->the_post();} ?>-->
```

Comment: Thanks the loop is currently working now

Comment: I've already did it :)

Comment: I mean upvote it and check it green :)